# Generic optional type with extends for typecheck

Tags: typescript

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=67#code/PTAEEMAcEtQJQKYEcCuCDOAXAUAYwPYB2WoARvgCYCeAXPMgEKVWgC8oA3mfvgNZ0BtAOTQKQgDSghmaJgA2CIQF1J4FJgAW%20AE6ChhcAFtFSgL54iJAGaE2EdFUK5QACgCUbAHydsoUAWJMbj46Jj4ABW18SHQAeV47cAB3cFlQKwRMXA0XIShoCU5yajoAKQBlWIA5ADosbWhCAHNoKyoXYqo3Uw9wdAhCKmxzbBBQTCpIDGwEAA9IHSCJqdAwhPYOX1BROnrGpq2ZeQRdzAbm4ewZ%20cXxyYRQAEF1LW07Tb8d0D2LvwNjU7nA4jZYPNYAMWgCDkFH67BEYlAAB8pEcFEJQNhQU8XjpIdDYXYERiUfojIpMaMwE0EIQEA1nNoMAtiA9sVYooYIDAsfcnjBEOg1gAecLQXC8BAUCFQmH9OaYWmEmUE9CSMUSqXPTR42WEhVK-ra174uXeVjYDW8YVrdXiyXSni8U2w7wAMh8fjUOt0oCtwuNOjtmooge0LvQnkuvJWa0i0Ti6350EFIuJyNRsnRkjJxiEUZjD0QSCY1HeW3IIVWTojAiUW29rwA-HQw7X6yMxkkNOAgq1tqAUoQlvh0plsqAiHIWJWEklZFp1BBcdom4XqxEojEABL4JIAFXwAFlwJKw7FIDIiOA5HZHgKMGnRCTM8d80A)

I want to make api request like this:

```
// api Request
const body: ReqBody = { book: ['id', 'title'], author: ['name']}
const fn = async () => {
  const book: BookPropsOk = await fetch('api', {body: JSON.stringify(body)}) as any
}
```

Problem is idn how to make type with optional author if i will fetch only book fields?

```
// types
export type Book = {
  id: string
  title: string
}

export type Author = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

type BookFields = 'id' | 'title' 
type AuthorFields = 'id' | 'name' 

// generic response type from api (CHANGE THIS)
type ApiResBook<PickedBookFields extends BookFields, PickedAuthorFields extends AuthorFields> =
Pick<Book, PickedBookFields> & {
  author: Pick<Author, PickedAuthorFields>
}

type BookPropsOk = ApiResBook<'id' | 'title', 'name'>

type ReqBody = {
  book: BookFields[]
  author?: AuthorFields[]
}

// what if i want to fetch only book without author?
type BookPropsHowToMakeAuthorOptional = ApiResBook<'id' | 'title'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, seems extends and pick works with [never default](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEEMAcEtQJQKYEcCuCDOAXAUAYwPYB2WoARvgCYCeAXPMgEKVWgC8oA3mfvgNZ0BtAOTQKQgDSghmaJgA2CIQF1J4FJgAW+AE6ChhcAFtFSgL54iJAGaE2EdFUK5QACgCUbAHydsoUAWJMbj46Jj4ABW18SHQAeV47cAB3cFlQKwRMXA0XIShoCU5yajoAKQBlWIA5ADosbWhCAHNoKyoXYqo3Uw9wdAhCKmxzbBBQTCpIDGwEAA9IHSCJqdAwhPYOX1BROnrGpq2ZeQRdzAbm4ewZ+cXxyYRQAEF1LW07Tb8d0D2LvwNjU7nA4jZYPNYAMWgCDkFH67BEYlAAB8pEcFEJQNhQU8XjpIdDYXYERiUfojIpMaMwE0EIQEA1nNoMAtiA9sVYooYIDAsfcnjBEOg1gAecLQXC8BAUCFQmH9OaYWmEmUE9CSMUSqXPTR42WEhVK-ra174uV2OkAN3p3lY2A1vGFa3V4sl0p4vFNsO8ADIfH41DrdKB7cLjTpnZqKGHtJ70J5LryVmtItE4ut+dBBSLicjUbJ0ZIycYhPHEw9EEgmNR3ltyCFVu7YwIlFsA68APx0aNNlsjMZJDTgIKtbagFKEJb4dKZbKgIhyFh1hJJWRadQQXHadtlhsRKIxAAS+CSABV8ABZcCS6OxSAyIjgOR2R4CjDZ0QkvPHEtAA):

```
type ApiResBook<PickedBookFields extends BookFields, PickedAuthorFields extends AuthorFields = never> =
Pick<Book, PickedBookFields> & {
  author: Pick<Author, PickedAuthorFields>
}
```